# XML to select a word (within code snippet)

Tags: xml, visual-studio, vscode-snippets

I have this snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<_locDefinition xmlns="urn:locstudio">
    <_locDefault _loc="locNone" />
    <_locTag _loc="locData">Title</_locTag>
    <_locTag _loc="locData">ToolTip</_locTag>
   <_locTag _loc="locData">Default</_locTag>
</_locDefinition>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
<Header>
<Title>pastDate</Title>
</Header>
<Snippet>
<Code Language="SQL"><![CDATA[DATEADD(,DATEDIFF(XXX,0,)-20,0)]]>
</Code>
</Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

How do I change it so that all of the word `XXX` is selected ?

Do I need to use either of the tags `$selected$` and/or `$end$` ?

Comment: @BartoszKP any ideas about possible answers

Comment: No, sorry. I've tried some simple things, but I don't use snippets much.

Comment: I assume you want to make this into a vscode snippet now?  Which part of that is the text actually inserted?  Just use a placeholder `${1:XXX}` and it will be selected and can be overwritten.

Comment: @Mark I’ll give that a go.... sounds like the answer.

Comment: You have to change it quite a bit to get it into vscode snippet syntax - I am not familiar with vs snippets.